# How are dev_*() family functions useful while debugging the Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

While searching for techniques to debugging a Linux kernel, one of the ways is to use the **dev_*()** family functions.

These functions are defined in the `/include/linux/device.h` file.

The function list is as below:

```
`dev_emerge()`<br>
`dev_alert()`<br>
`dev_crit()`<br>
`dev_err()`<br>
`dev_warning()`<br>
`dev_notice()`<br>
`dev_info()`<br>
```

I have already experimented with the **pr_*()**[`pr_emerge()`, `pr_alert()`, `pr_crit()`...] family functions, which are similar to **printk()** in some way.

An experiment is done using simple kernel modules where I'm calling these functions. Furthermore I have also gone through a priority of messages displayed in `syslog` and `dmesg` (kernel ring buffer depending console_loglevel-a kernel variable).

But I'm unable to understand the use of **dev_*()** family. I mean, how do I use it in a program to debug kernel functionality?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `pr_*()` functions are the same as plain `printk()`, but with the `KERN_xxx` log level already included.

The `dev_*()` functions are the same as the corresponding `pr_*()` functions, but also print identifying information about the `struct device`.

If your message is related to some device (which is normally the case in drivers), you should use `dev_*()`.
For example, in a USB driver:

```
struct usb_device *usb_dev;
dev_info(&usb_dev->dev, "hello\n");

struct usb_interface *usb_intf;
dev_info(&usb_intf->dev, "hello\n");
```

or in a PCI driver:

```
struct pci_dev *pci;
dev_info(&pci->dev, "hello\n");
```

Comment: Is it, along with pushing info on Kernel Ring Buffer, it will also put some info inside device specific log, dev_*() function?? if it is so, where dev specific logs are located?

Comment: That information just gets prefixed to the actual message.

Comment: do we really need "\n" at the end?

Answer (score 4):

`dev_*` functions are similar to `pr_*`, but also print some information about device(`struct device`), passed to them as the first argument. This information may help to filter system log for messages, belonging to concrete device.

So, you can use `dev_*` function instead of `pr_*` whenever message is applicable to concrete device(and you have destriptor of it).

Answer (score 3):

**Check what it prints yourself with QEMU**

This is what it prints for a PCI device:

```
<6>lkmc_pci 0000:00:04.0: pci_probe
```

which is of format:

```
<level><kernel-module> <pci-address>: <message>
```

So as others said, it gives extra device information compared to a simple `printk`, namely:

- kernel module name
- PCI address

I tested that with QEMU's "edu" device, which is simple educational PCI device, for which I wrote [a minimal Linux kernel module](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/b1b2817a689464e35c799274c4ceedcfed37e475/kernel_module/pci.c#L170).

The key module code is:

```
static int pci_probe(struct pci_dev *dev, const struct pci_device_id *id)
{   
    dev_info(&(dev->dev), "pci_probe\n");
```

Character devices don't expose a `struct device` apparently, so you can't test it that way: [How do you get a struct device for a Linux character device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836712/how-do-you-get-a-struct-device-for-a-linux-character-device)